# Keras error: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, keras, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I have this code (part of code) from RaGan ( Relativistic average Gan):

```
def get_ragan_network(generator,discriminator,optimizer):
    imgs_hr = Input(image_shape)
    generated_hr = Input(image_shape)

    Discriminator_real_out = discriminator(imgs_hr)
    Discriminator_fake_out = discriminator(generated_hr)


    Real_Fake_relativistic_average_out = tf.add(Discriminator_real_out,-(K.mean(Discriminator_fake_out, axis=0)))
    Fake_Real_relativistic_average_out = tf.add(Discriminator_fake_out,-(K.mean(Discriminator_real_out, axis=0)))

    epsilon=0.000001 
    def relativistic_discriminator_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        if isinstance(Real_Fake_relativistic_average_out, np.ndarray):
            return -(K.mean(K.log(K.sigmoid(Real_Fake_relativistic_average_out)+epsilon ),axis=0)
                 +K.mean(K.log(1-K.sigmoid(Fake_Real_relativistic_average_out)+epsilon),axis=0))
        else:
            return -(K.mean(K.log(K.sigmoid(Real_Fake_relativistic_average_out)+epsilon ),axis=0)
                 +K.mean(K.log(1-K.sigmoid(Fake_Real_relativistic_average_out)+epsilon),axis=0))

    model = Model([generated_hr,imgs_hr],[Discriminator_real_out,Discriminator_fake_out])

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=[relativistic_discriminator_loss,None])
    return model
```

but when I execute the code I obtain this error:

`Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.`

I dont know how to solve that.

Numpy version = 1.19

tensorflow version = 2.6

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from this line: `isinstance(Real_Fake_relativistic_average_out, np.ndarray)`, because `Real_Fake_relativistic_average_out` comes from the discriminator output and `np.ndarray` is a numpy object. And apparently, the conditional if else statement is useless.

Comment: No no, that is not the error, if I remove the conditional if else I get the same error. I have probed others old examples from DRaGan, RaGan, etc ... and all give me the same error. Ithink the problem could be the numpy version or tensorflow version, but I need to find a solution without downgrade versions.